# log4j2 with two rollingfile appenders not zipping one of them

Tags: java, zip, log4j2

Using log4j2 version 2.9.1 with the following log4j2.xml on Tomcat 7.0.41.

The config file is specified to the Tomcat service using the -Dlog4j.configurationFile= construct.  The two appenders are used by two different webapps that instantiate with:

```
Logger loggwe = Logger.getLogger("RollingFile 'name' here");
```

**Problem:** The "dislog" appender rolls but never zips.

The "applog" appender zips as expected.  Other portions of the dislog config, such as the Pattern, are used correctly so each webapp does use its section accordingly. One just won't zip.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="60" status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="dislog" fileName="D:/DocVue/apache-tomcat/webapps/DIS/WEB-INF/logs/dis.log" filePattern="D:/DocVue/apache-tomcat/webapps/DIS/WEB-INF/logs/dis-%d{MM-dd-yy}.%i.log.zip" append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>D %-5p %d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m [%t]:%C.%M:%L%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="9" fileIndex="max">
                <Delete basePath="D:/DocVue/apache-tomcat/webapps/DIS/WEB-INF/logs">
                    <IfAny>
                        <IfLastModified age="30d" />
                        <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="100 MB" />
                    </IfAny>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="applog" fileName="D:/DocVue/docvue/WEB-INF/log/docvue.log" filePattern="D:/DocVue/docvue/WEB-INF/log/docvue-%d{MM-dd-yy}.%i.log.zip" append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%-5p %d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m [%t]:%C.%M:%L%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="9" fileIndex="max">
                <Delete basePath="D:/DocVue/docvue/WEB-INF/log">
                    <IfAny>
                        <IfLastModified age="30d" />
                        <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="100 MB" />
                    </IfAny>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m [%t]:%C.%M:%L%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="applog" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="applog"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="dislog" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="dislog"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this problem arises from a race condition - you have two apps both trying to use the same appenders and thus the same log files.

It might be a coincidence that one appender *appears* to work correctly - maybe one app does its logging to that appender earlier and by the time the second app logs to that appender there is no interleaving.

When I run a simplified example I am only able to duplicate the failure to zip log files by executing two applications at the same time **in separate JVMs** that both use your configuration.

It's important to note that [Tomcat by default deploys web applications into the same JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081977/3284624). So in order to know whether this problem is due to the race condition I've described more information about your runtime environment is needed.

Lastly, I think if you work on creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you may gain insight into the problem and it would help those who are trying to help you.